# Sistema de busca no próprio site, como linkar tantas páginas e reconhecer os caracteres digitados

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou com uma barra de pesquisas aqui, porém como eu faço buscas das minhas htmls em meu próprio diretório do pc?

```js
function executar(){ 
  var tx= document.getElementById('tx').value;
  var lista = document.getElementById('ht');
  var adicionar= true;
  var opt = document.createElement('option');

   for(i=0; i <lista.options.length;i++){
    if(tx==lista.options[i].value){
     adicionar=false;
    }
   }
   if(adicionar==true){
    opt.value=tx;
    lista.appendChild(opt);
   }
}
```

```css
.ps{ width: 400px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 200px auto;

}
#tx{ width: 350px;
 height: 40px;
 float: left;
 font-family: 'Arial';
 font-size: 20px;

}
.bt{ width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #2f4550;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 cursor: pointer;

}
#tx:focus{ border:2px solid #2f4550;

}
```

```html
<form class="ps">
 <input type="search" id="tx" list="ht" placeholder="pesquisar">
 <img src="" class="bt" onclick="executar()">
<datalist id="ht">
 <option value="Css"></option>
 <option value="Games"></option>
 <option value="Html"></option>
 <option value="C++"></option>
</datalist> 
</form>
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor, não ficou muito claro. Se script adiciona options inexistentes com o que foi digitado na busca, e o que mais é pra fazer?

Comment: Sim ele memoriza o que o usuario digitou

Comment: agora eu queria outro script para fazer busca na minha própria página

Comment: "_agora eu queria outro script para fazer busca na minha própria página_"... Buscar oq? Essa parte que não ficou clara.

Comment: queria um que eu pudesse editar e linkar minha páginas

Comment: buscar o conteúdo do meu diretório

Comment: que ao digitar algo especifico na barra ela se direcionar para algum link das minha páginas no meu diretório do pc

Comment: é uma barra de pesquisa normal mesmo, só que de busca interna

Comment: Tá, mas se sair da página, o datalist vai voltar ao estado original. Logo o script que adiciona itens ao datalist se torna inútil.

Comment: pode até tirar esse script aí, eu só queria fazer uma barra para pesquisar na minha propria pasta onde estão minha htmls

Comment: Coloque todos os detalhes na pergunta, isso evita ficar aqui nos comentários debatendo, o que é muito ruim.

Comment: Vou votar pra fechar a pergunta por _falta de clareza_... se a qualidade melhorar eu retiro o voto. Boa sorte aí!

Comment: Você vai precisar de Banco de Dados - exemplo Mysql -  e uma linguagem server-side - exemplo PHP. Você dispõe dessas ferramentas?

Comment: Ainda não cheguei a entrar nesse assunto, por enquanto ainda estou estudando html / css e um pouco de JS

Comment: Seria possível apenas usar só Mysql?? da para fazer com Js??

Comment: acho que não, eu desconheço